# Cannot convert value of type 'Image' to expected argument type 'UIImage'

Tags: core-data, swiftui, uiimage

I am using an ImagePicker to select an Image from Library and store in CoreData (as Binary). In another view this selected image is shown as a thumbnail.

I want the user to be free when selecting an image. If he doesn't select an image, it should show a default Thumbnail (which is already shown in the placeholder).

My question is whether the Code below is right logically but not well implemented.

```
ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {

                                Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: Group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image)!)
                                    .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
                                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                                    .frame(height: 200.0, alignment: .center)
                                    .cornerRadius(22)
```

My Idea would be to do it this way, but it says that this does not work.

```
ZStack (alignment: .bottomLeading) {

    Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: Group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? Image("defaultGroupThumbnail"))
        .resizable(capInsets: EdgeInsets())
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
        .frame(height: 200.0, alignment: .center)
        .cornerRadius(22)
```

I appreciate any advice. Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: Group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? Image("defaultGroupThumbnail"))
```

This is providing a default value for `UIImage` using an `Image`, hence the type mismatch.
Replace it with:

```
 Image(uiImage: UIImage(data: Group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? UIImage(named: "defaultGroupThumbnail"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked. But I had to add a "!". Like following: // Image(uiImage: (UIImage(data: Group.groupThumbnail ?? self.image) ?? UIImage(named: "defaultGroupThumbnail"))!)

Comment: No problem as long as the image is in your assets folder